How to send StreamingResponseBody and display response asynchronously in Spring Boot
I have a demo app with a simple controller that sends streaming data. When I send a request from the browser, the code below writes to the console every second, but the response is delayed until all the results are concatenated and sent at once.
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody;

@RestController
public class DemoController {
    @GetMapping(path = "/demo")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> demo() {
        final StreamingResponseBody responseBody = out -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                out.write(String.format("Hello, World %d\n", i).getBytes());
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("Send " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseBody, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

How can I make the response display messages asynchronously, as they are sent, without waiting for the full concatenation?
This demo project was created by VS Code's Spring Initializr.
